# Robolectric: Tests are run on UI Thread (id=1), blocks my BroadcastReceiver

Tags: deadlock, robolectric, android-testing, ui-thread

I have a problem with Robolectric. I don't understand how it works.
The tests seem to run on Android's UI Thread (Thread ID=1). However if I send a broadcast from the test code, and then wait for it to arrive in a BroadcastReceiver in the test, then the BroadcastReceiver will be blocked because it is also on Thread ID=1. How can I test such behaviour then?

Comment: 1. Post your code.
2. I would avoid `robolectric` when your test heavily depends on Android SDK. I would prefer instrumentation tests in this case.

Comment: It was just that is was so many tests and so tiring to have to install it onto a device all the time that drove me to use Robolectric.

Comment: @JohnyText Yeah, but unfortunately Robolectric has it's own disadvantages. For Example. 1. You test against Robolectric's SDK implementation not against real one. 2. There are bugs. Like this one https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1986 that makes your tests flaky.